# Cannot enable "Track Edits" on ArcGIS Online Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-online, feature-layer

I have a feature layer that is published to ArcGIS Online and being edited by users there.  I am not able to enable "Track Edits" for this feature layer.  Under the feature layer properties, when I click on "edit", check the "Track Edits" option and click save, the feature layer still shows Track Edits as being disabled.

I have previously been able to enable track edits for feature layers successfully but now it just won't enable.  I've tried this on a couple feature layers and none of them allow me to enable track edits.  Anyone out there experience this issue/know of a solution?

This screenshot shows where I enable "Track Edits" with a check mark.

[image: enabled]

This screenshot is what I see after clicking save on the previous image.  Track Edits is disabled.

[image: disabled]

Comment: Have you enabled editor tracking on the feature in your database?

Comment: Its a shapefile that's published to a feature layer.  I see nothing in the shapefile properties (if that's what you're referring to) that would enable editing.

Comment: I've added screenshots in the original question.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I found out that a bug was causing my issue.
http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMTAyMjk1

Answer (score 1):

As commented by the asker (@Steve):

> a bug was causing [the] issue.
>   http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMTAyMjk1

which says:

> **Bug NIM102295**
>
> Synopsis
>
> If the editor tracking fields (Creation Date, Creator, Last Edit Date,
>   Editor) are present in a hosted feature service, Track Edits cannot be
>   enabled on the feature service in ArcGIS Online.